# What is the C# equivalence for the JAVA `System.exit(0);`?

Tags: c#, java

What is the C# equivalence for `System.exit(0);` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 76):

If you are using a Console Application -

```
Environment.Exit(exitCode);
```

Else if you are using a Windows Forms based application -

```
Application.Exit();
```

Courtesy: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/273503-java-systemexit0%3B-equivalent-in-c%23/

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`Environment.Exit(0)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.  Note that this is somewhat more complicated than Java due to some permissions issues, but in general this is the symmetrical equivalent.

You can read more about the possible Exceptions thrown in the linked documentation.